Standard definitions of some notions in algebraic geometry (canonical divisor, Q-Gorenstein, (log-)canonical/terminal, Fano, Calabi-Yau, General type)
I have a question about several related notions in algebraic geometry. I am mainly interested in the question "what is the standard notion?" (if there is such). But I also will be happy to know what is the "natural boundary" of the definition.

The canonical divisor: I saw a definition for a normal variety of  the canonical divisor as a Weil  divisor (closure of the canonical divisor on the regular set). Is this notion defined in the non-Normal case? Up to what this notion well defined?
Quasi-Gorenstein/$\mathbb Q$-Gorenstein variety: I saw a definition for a normal variety that is based on the above notion of canonical divisor. Do those notions require Normality? This looks weird since it would mean that Gorenstein is not necessarily Quasi-Gorenstein or $\mathbb Q$-Gorenstein (as it is not necessarily normal)
(log-)canonical/terminal, Fano, Calabi-Yaw, General type variety: I saw a definition for a normal variety that is based on the above notion of canonical divisor. However it uses the word "ample" which I do not understand when it refers to a general Weil divisor . Does this mean that these notions are defined only for $\mathbb Q$-Gorenstein varieties?
Do I understand correctly that though the notions of (log-)canonical/terminal and rational singularities have anlaoges for positive characteristic, non of these analogs are considered standard.
Thanks a lot


Definitely the Mori program does make use of the dualizing sheaf in the non-normal case, since in many instances (e.g., inversion of adjunction), the proofs proceed by induction where the induction step passes to a simple normal crossings divisor (or something weaker, e.g., semi-log-canonical divisor) that need not be normal.  In most instances, the reflexive hull of some positive tensor power of the dualizing sheaf is an invertible sheaf, so that we can treat the dualizing sheaf as a Weil divisor that is $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier.

I did not understand the last sentence. Can you elaborate?

The Mori program (as originally conceived) applies to projective schemes that are Cohen-Macaulay (so that they have a coherent dualizing sheaf $\omega$) such that, for some positive integer $n$, the double dual of $\omega^{\otimes n}$ is an invertible sheaf.  Then this dualizing sheaf plays the role of a canonical divisor class.  When the scheme is also normal, there is an associated Weil divisor class of the dualizing sheaf, and $n$ times that Weil divisor class is the Weil divisor class of a Cartier divisor.

Thank you for the explanations. I have more followup questions: What is double dual of a sheaf? What is "Weil divisor class"? Are you proposing the following definition to Q-Gorenstein for Cohen-Macaulay variety: "the double dual of a power of the dualizing sheaf is invertible"? Does this definition appear in the literature? 
So, is the notion of Q-Gorenstein defined either for normal varieties or for Cohen-Macaulay varieties? Is there a natural joint generalization of these 2 frameworks?

Double dual means applying $\mathcal{H}\mathrm{om}(-, \mathcal{O}_X)$ twice. Weil divisor class the class of Weil divisors up to linear equivalence.  Yes, that definition appears in the literature for normal schemes, and even when the scheme is not Cohen-Macaulay.  I would say it's the standard definition.  Q-Gorenstein is typically defined for normal varieties regardless of whether they are Cohen-Macaulay, however some people have an additional Cohen-Macaulay assumption.  I don't think we have a framework outside of the normal case (or at least outside of the G1 + S2 case).

Thank you very much. Does G1 and S1 mean Gorenstein outside co-dimension 2 and smooth outside co-dimension 3?

G1 means Gorenstein in codimension 1.  S2 means Serre's condition (it's related to depth).

Thank you very much. I just understood that my interpretation of S2 did not make sense...   I still do not understand how to define te canonical divisor in this case.  The definition proposed by  Jason Starr requires to have the dualizing sheaf $\omega$. I can imagine the following definition: use the definition proposed by  Jason Starr outside the non-Cohen-Macaully (or non-Gorenstein) locus. Then extend by taking the closer (the way it is done in the normal case). Is this what you mean?
